# Translation between two cameras

Tags: opencv, linear-algebra, camera-calibration, affinetransform

I have two cameras with R1,T1 and R2,T2 rotation and translation matrices calibrated w.r.t checkerboard coordinate system. My questions:

1. Which point on checkerboard is assumed to be the coordinate system, maybe the center?
2. How can I find the translation and rotation between two cameras?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The coordinates system is located at the first inner corner of the pattern. More correctly, this depends on the array of object points passed to solvePnP or FindExtrinsicCameraParams2.
2. You have to calculate the first camera's inverse transformation matrix R1',-R1'*T1 (':transpose matrix, *:matrices product). Then you have to compose the transformation between the cameras: R2*R1', -(R2*R1'*T1)+T2. Please verify this, because I am not sure.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm also facing similar problem

Comment: When you are calculating "-(R2*R1'*T1)+T2", you are basically converting Translation of 1st camera to coordinates of the second and subtracting. But shouldn't it be the other way round?